# Solve $x^2$ $mod$ $23 = 7^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

What is the procedure to solving $x^2$ $mod$ $23 = 7^2$? According to WolframAlpha, there is no integer solution but I am completely confused as to what steps was taken to determine that.

Before asking the question, I did try to solve this using brute force by plugging in some arbitrary numbers to see whether the square of that number mod $23$ gave me a remainder of $49$ but the procedure was quite tedious. Hence the reason I turned to WolframAlpha.

Going back to the question, I want to know how WoflramAlpha determined that there was no integer solution to solving for $x$.

Comment: Did you try putting it in [like this?](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2+%3D+7%5E2+mod+23)

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584922/integer-m-has-primitive-root-if-and-only-if-the-only-solutions-of-the-congruen#comment1236052_584922

Comment: Before tetori edited the question, it was as follows: $x^2$ mod 23 = $7^2$. Are the two statements equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what WolframAlpha did, and it would be helpful if you posted a link to the result of your input.  However, it should be fairly obvious that there is at least one solution to this equation, namely, if $x \equiv 7 \pmod{23}$, certainly $x^2 \equiv 7^2 \pmod{23}$.

It turns out you have the additional solution of $x \equiv -7 \equiv 16 \pmod{23}$, and that's it.  In fact, whenever you're solving a quadratic equation modulo a prime, you will have at most two roots, sometimes one, and sometimes none.

Comment: Perhaps Alpha is interpreting mod 23 as an operator, so $7^2\pmod{23}$ is evaluated as 3, and then it's $x^2=3$ that has no integer solution.

Comment: But W|A does give the correct solutions! http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20%3D%207%5E2%20(mod%2023)&t=crmtb01

Comment: I am actually trying to solve $x^2$ $mod$ $23 = 7^2$.

Comment: Well, you'll never get a remainder of $49$ because the remainder upon division by $23$ is always a number from $0$ to $22$.  However, you can get a solution to $x^2 \mod{23} = 7^2 \mod{23}$, which is what I discuss above.