# Solution to $x^2$ mod $23=7^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Recently, I stumbled upon this problem, [Solve $x^2$ $mod$ $23 = 7^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586423/solve-x2-mod-23-72?noredirect=1#comment1238227_586423), both here at MSE and somewhere surfing the web. I tried to solve it but don't know how. Although I can't remember where I found it, I doremember the question saying to solve the equation for $x$ rather than to determine whether some sort of solution existed. So by that, I presume that there is a such solution that I am not seeing.

I tried the following: $1^2$ mod $23$, $2^2$ mod $23$, $3^2$ mod $23$, $...$ , $22^2$ mod $23$. Following this procedure did not yield an answer of $49$. Can anyone show me how a solution is determined because it has been over 2 days and it is driving me crazy from my inability to see the solution.

Comment: My advice is that you should familiarize yourself with the difference between [binary mod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) that calculates the remainder of integer division, and [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). Whenever an algebraist write `mod` the latter is meant almost always (and $x^2\equiv7^2\pmod {23}$ surely has solutions $x\equiv\pm7$). Many programmers have note heard of the latter meaning, and only know of the remainder operation. $a\bmod b$ that returns an integer with absolute value less than $|b|$.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a modulus like $23$ means that the result class should be considered as well as the variable's class.  So we have $7^2\equiv 3\pmod{23}$ and thus you are looking for numbers $x$ such that $x^2\equiv 3\pmod{23}$.  One such number will be $7$ due to the nature of the modular equation.  We also know that $(-1)^2=1$.  Putting these two together, we get $(-7)^2=7^2\equiv 3\pmod{23}$.  Then we consider the class of $-7\pmod{23}$, which is the same class as $16\pmod{23}$.

Moving in reverse, we have identified that $16^2\equiv 7^2\equiv 3\pmod{23}$.  Rewriting as an equation, we have $16^2+a\cdot 23=7^2+b\cdot 23=3$, yielding $a=-11,b=-2$.  Then we can state that $16^2=256=207+49\equiv 49+0=3+46\pmod{23}$.  This is the case since $49$ and $3$ are in the same class modulo $23$.

Answer (score 1):

$7^2\equiv x^2 \text { mod } 23$ i.e., $23$ divides $x^2-7^2$ i.e., $23$ divides either $x+7$ or $x-7$

Suppose it divides both :

$23=(x+7)k=(x-7)l=kx+7k=lx-7l\Rightarrow x(k-l)=-7(k-l)\Rightarrow x=??$

Suppose it divides only one :

$23=(x+7)k\Rightarrow k=\pm1,\pm23\Rightarrow x=??$

$23=(x-7)k\Rightarrow k=\pm1,\pm23\Rightarrow x=??$