# primitive root of modulo 9 and modulo 28

Tags: number-theory

What are the primitive roots of modulo 9 and modulo 28?

I tried to solve this problem after   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n

Elementary example, but it seems to be to long for me. are there any opportunietes to give the primitive roots of modulo 9 and modulo 28?

Comment: and how can I find the order of modulo 9 and modulo 28? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584922/integer-m-has-primitive-root-if-and-only-if-the-only-solutions-of-the-congruen

Comment: There is no primitive root modulo $28$. For $9$, try everything, you will find them. (There are two.)

Comment: A primitive root modulo $n$ exists only if $n$ is a power of an odd prime, twice the power of an odd prime, or a factor of four. 9 fits the first group (2 is a primitive root), but 28 does not.

Answer (score 2):

One of the primitive root modulo $9$ is $2$ since we have $2,4,8,7,5,1$.

The number of primitive roots mod $n$ in case any exist is $\varphi(\varphi(n))$

To see why $28$ has no primitive roots us charmichaels theorem to see

$\lambda(28)=lcm(\varphi(4),\varphi(7))=lcm(2,6)=6$

Comment: Note that $9$ has two primitive roots.

Comment: thank you very much, 
and how can I find the order of modulo 9 and modulo 28?

Comment: what do you mean?